# The system cannot find the file activatorconfig.txt

Tags: java, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm using play framework 2.3. I follow the instructions on page https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing to install activator. It looks like activator is successfully installed. When I input activator commands, it gives me right output except two lines on top:

The system cannot find the file C:\Users\myname\.activator\1.2.12\activatorconfig.txt.

The system cannot find the file C:\Users\myname\.activator\activatorconfig.txt.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried deleting `~/.activator/version-0.properties`

Comment: The folder C:\Users\myname\ has a space in it. This causes the error.