# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when using Play framework 2.3

Tags: java, windows, scala, playframework

I'm getting this error but I don't know where is the problem.

I'm running on Windows 7. I already try delete the folders .activator, .ivy2, .sbt, I try to download the activator again, and modify the variable system PATH to activator trying to find any problem with the jdk or jre, but nothing.

```
$ activator
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sbt.Classpaths$.sbt$Classpaths$$bootRepository(Defaults.scala:1758)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1729)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

When I open the .bat I get this message:

```
The system cannot find file C:\Users\XXX\.activator\1.3.2\activatorconfig.txt
The system cannot find file C:\Users\XXX\.activator\activatorconfig.txt
```

Whatever the command I send to activator it returns this error, with exception the "new" command.

Any clues?

Comment: I've never used Play under MS Windows so far. Just a guess: Can you find this `activatorconfig.txt` under the path in your error message? If not try to create an empty file with the name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance trying the run Activator from Git Bash (MINGW32)?

If so, try running it from Command Prompt.

I accidentally did this and got exactly the same error, I'm also on Windows 7 and have just updated to Play Framework 2.4.0.

Comment: Yes! I was doing that, but when I run from the cmd I get this mesage: 

'The system cannot find the file C:\Users\XXX\.activator\1.3.2\activatorconfig.txt.
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\XXX\.activator\activatorconfig.txt.
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.'

Comment: Common things I'm seeing... 1) Does the folder name have a space in it? - i.e. "...\John Smith\..."(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305364/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-activatorconfig-txt) 2) Try deleting `~/.activator/version-0.properties`

Comment: I try delete that folder as I already said before but nothing changes.